# Need to design tree chart in my iOS app

Tags: ios, json, charts, google-visualization

I have to design tree chart like 
[Google tree map chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap)

I have to also know about proper json which will design this chart in proper format
Thanks

Comment: Why vote down for this question......

Comment: I didn't vote, but these kind of "wishlist" questions ("I need X and Y, please tell me how to do it") tend to get downvoted and/or closed. A good question would contain information about what you've found through your own research; ideally some relevant pieces of your code, and a description of the ways in which the code isn't working as expected (including error messages if there are any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think TreeMapKit for iOS does this:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/treemapkit